# BIRT Report Designer: Table of Contents (TOC) with page number and hyperlink

Tags: eclipse, reporting, birt, tableofcontents

I'm using BIRT report designer v4.8 and trying to build a table of contents(TOC).
I know that BIRT has a builtin Table of Contents in Properties, but that kind of TOC can only be viewed in the Web Viewer by clicking the "Toggle table of contents" and be showed up on the left side of the report.

What I want to do is to create a TOC that is **part of the report**, which means the TOC is directly showed up as a section in the report without clicking the "Toggle table of contents", and also can be exported along with the report.

For example, here is a sample of TOC, suppose we have four sections in the report.
[image]

The challenge I'm facing now is calculating the page numbers for each section and then add a hyperlink for each section so that the page will jump to that section when a user clicks it from the TOC. Does anyone know how to get this functionality? What kind of scripts do I need?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with BIRT alone.

A possible solution is depending on the output format.

With PDF and a good knowledge of iText, it should be possible to create a TOC in a post-processing step.

I'll sketch the idea here (assuming that the TOC will fit on one page):

With BIRT, generate your invisible TOC as before. On the first page, leave enough room for the TOC.

The rest of the work will happen after BIRT has generated the PDF. BIRT contains iText and iText can examine and modify existing PDFs.

In PDF speech, the TOC is called "outline". With iText, examine the outline. This will give you the data you need for your visible TOC and can be transformed to an array of triples of the form (toc_level, toc_text, page_no).

Then you can create a new PDF with the help of iTexts PDFStamper class: Take the existing PDFs and render your list of triples on page 1.

This will cost you *at least* 1-2 days of Java development work, however.